# Managing long/heavy functions in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm using this:

```
# $file = '/path/existing_file.jpg';
# $info = getimagesize($file);
# $target = '/path/newfile.jpg';

function imgCreator($file, $info, $target, $size) {
  list($width, $height) = $info;
  $w = $size;

 if ($size > 300) {
    if ($size > 800) {
        $h = ($size/16)*9;
    } else {
        $h = ($size/16)*10;
    }
  } else {
    $h = $size;
  }
  $r = $width/$height;

  if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $nWidth = $h*$r;
        $nHeight = $h;
    } else {
        $nHeight = $w/$r;
        $nWidth = $w;
    }

  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
    imagealphablending($dst, false);
    imagesavealpha($dst,true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($dst, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $transparent);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $width, $height);
    imagepng($dst, $target);
  } else {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($nWidth, $nHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nWidth, $nHeight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($dst, $target);
  }
  imagedestroy($dst);
}
```

to create an image of specified resolution and width to height ratio based on wanted size.

It works well for making thumbnails etc. but any bigger size given, like let's say `2000px` will cause problems. Basically the whole script including this function stops working as soon as it reaches the callout, with absolutely no `echo` or whatever output from whole script, even if it occured before executing it, however other operations before that function are being executed. Typically in this case I'm making a couple of diffrent sized images, and it seems like the `$size` is the only problem here.

I assume it would be perfect to do such tasks in the background, but I'm quite a beginner and I'm not sure, if I want to learn how to do this right now, especially if it's going to be only one person using this at a time.

So my question is, **what is the cause of the problem here, and how should I deal with it?**

Comment: well, start by looking at your logs (web server, php, php-fpm if you use it). Most likely a process size issue that can usually be adjusted with some .ini parameters. But without details from the log, it is a pure guess.

Comment: Right, it looks like it used up all the memory.

Comment: Is there any way to make this function use less memory for its task, or do I have to change the limit?